# locking $resource calls in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, locking

We're using a $resource to perform REST calls to our server, but people tend to doubleclick the button that initiates the call.
I already implemented a simple locking mechanism by setting a lock at initialisation of the call to the resource, and checking if it is locked before it fires, but somehow people still manage to fire of multiple calls.

```
if (lock === false) {
   lock = true;

    myService.mycall({ key: value },
                function (result) {
                    ..some code...
                    lock = false;
                },
                function (result) {
                    ..some code..
                    lock = false;
     });
```

Is there a way to somehow lock this in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I use ng-disable with all inputs when I do any ajax call to insure exactly this does not happen:

```
<button ng-click="saveChanges()"
    ng-disabled="pageLoad"
    class="save">Save</button>

$scope.saveChanges = function() {
    $scope.pageLoad = true;
    myResource.save($scope.data)
    .success(function(response)  {
        $scope.pageLoad = false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the $resource action is executed asynchronously through callbacks. the execution moves on to unlock before server return.

try unlock in resource callback function

Comment: sorry, I didn't make that clear enough probably, the unlock is set in the callback for a 200 and for error cases, and at initialization of the controller... see my updated question